# What is a concise way to abbreviate a series of number descending/ascending numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I'm working with a bunch of sequences that descend and then ascend back to their starting point, such as $\{1,3,5,7,5,3,1\}$ or $\{10,9,8,...,8,9,10\}$. Is there a concise notation I can use to indicate these sequences descend and then ascend back to their starting point, or the converse, ascend then descend?

Comment: There isn't any universal notation (that I am aware of), but of course you could introduce one in context.

Comment: You shouldn't use curly braces to denote sequences - people will think you're referring to sets and say confusing things.

Comment: You can define a "mountain sequence" and then just use that term.

Comment: Are you looking for palindromic sequences? The examples you give are palindromic, but palindromic doesn’t necessarily mean a single *peak*. Eg. $4, 7, 5,2, 8, 9, 8, 2, 5, 7, 4$ is palindromic, but $7, 9$ may be considered local peaks.

Comment: To stress: whatever you define, you should define it clearly.  I assumed you meant palindromes that increase (or decrease) monotonically to their peak (or trough) but of course you didn't say that anywhere. A sequence like $\{1,3,5,7,4,2,1\}$ also ascends to a peak and then descends back to the start.  As would be $\{1,3,5,7,1\}$ though you don't want to allow that one (I am guessing).  Whatever notion you want is fine, of course, it's just important to be clear about it.